# How to run “git submodule init” and how to “build” a program

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, steambot

I want to include [SteamBot](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot) in my project but I'm already stumped on the first step, which is the setup step.

From the README of SteamBot:

> **Step 0:** If you've just recently cloned this repository, there are a few things you need to do.
>
> 1. Run `git submodule init` to initialize the sub-module configuration file.
> 2. Run `git submodule update` to pull the latest version of the sub-modules that are included (namely, SteamKit2).
> 3. Build the program. Since SteamKit2 is licensed under the LGPL, and SteamBot should be released under the MIT license, SteamKit2's code cannot be included in SteamBot. This includes executables. We'll probably make downloads available on GitHub.
> 4. Continue on like normal.

I think "cloned" would mean simply clicking the "Clone in Windows" button on the website, right? But I do not know how to "run `git submodule init`" or how to "build the program". It would be great if anyone could tell me specifically what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as you seem to be using *Github for Windows* and cloned SteamBot with the "Clone in Windows" button, I can tell you that you don't need to touch the submodules (or run `git submodule init` or `... update`), because *Github for Windows* has already done that for you when you cloned the repo. That takes care of numbers 1 and 2.

From what I can tell, SteamBot is a Visual Studio project (there's a *.csproj and a *.sln file), so building it should be a matter of opening it (i.e. the Solution, the *.sln file) in Visual Studio and clicking the *Build* button.

But if you don't know what building means or how it is done for C# (which I guess you're using for your own project too), you should probably get to know C# and Visual Studio more, before you plunge into this. Building a project is one of the very basic things you should know how to do.

Comment: Oh I did try to build it.  It's the same as debugging right? But when I open the project with visual studio it says it can't reference the files from the "lib " folder which I guess is the submodule?

Comment: I'll come up with more details later , I'm out currently.  Sorry I used my phone to type this and the above comment